# AWS Security Check box is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services

My login flow for AWS is blocked because the security check box shows a blank field. The audio button doesn't play anything (not even the background noise that it usually plays).[image]

Comment: Something looks very wrong with that page. Try a different browser, or see whether a plugin is impacting it. Possibly even try via a different network (eg home vs office vs tethered via phone), since those error messages suggest a network-related problem.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein - That error is coming from Chrome (where password manager extension is installed). I tried again in firefox and got authenticated. Not sure why a password manager should interfere with auth in aws? Thank you again.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. In Firefox, I can get to the logged in home page, but anything I click after that generates a message that says: An error occurred during a connection to s3.console.aws.amazon.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

Comment: Could it be that AWS doesn't like my VPN?

Comment: It's very probable that the error you get is due to your vpn. Have you tried after disabling your vpn or changing your network and try to open it in an incognito window.

Comment: ill try it when i get back to my desk. why wouldnt aws allow a vpn?

Comment: It is more likely that your VPN (or corporate network) is blocking some access to AWS.

Comment: I can login if I turn my vpn off. It's so weird that the vpn would block aws.